# chrome.tabs.onUpdated listener with script execution works strangely after first load

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm writing a chrome extension to remove elements from a specific page after it loads and I am seeing inconsistent behavior.

I have two listeners, one is listening for hotkeys and the other is the chrome.tabs.onUpdated listener. Both make an executeScript call to the same additional file.

OnUpdated fails with a manifest permission error at first, and continues to fail on each reload. When I execute the call from the hot key it works, and then the ***onUpdated call works with subsequent reloads***

If I open the page in a new tab, it is back to failing until I execute the call with the hotkey. It also goes back to failing if I reload the extension from the management page.

Am I missing something obvious? I have tried adding `http://*/*` to my permissions but the behavior is the same.

backgroud.js

```js
chrome.commands.onCommand.addListener(function (command) {
  if (command === "test-alert") {
    try {
      chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {file: "testalert.js"});
      } catch(err) {
          chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage().console.log(err);
      }   
  }
});

chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(tabId, changeInfo, tab){
  if(changeInfo.status === "complete" && tab.url.includes("nytimes")){
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabId, {file: "testalert.js"});
  };
});
```

manifest.json

```
"commands": {
  "test-alert": {
    "suggested_key": {
      "default": "Ctrl+M",
      "mac": "Command+M"
    },
    "description": "test alert"
  }
}
```

testalert.js

```js
alert("test");
```

Error:

```
Unchecked runtime.lastError: Cannot access contents of url "https://www.nytimes.com". Extension manifest must request permission to access this host.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Am I missing something obvious?

Looks like so. Look at the error message more closely:

```
Cannot access contents of url "https://www.nytimes.com"
```

The protocol is `https`, not `http`. You should use `https://*/*` in your manifest `"permissions"`, or maybe even `<all_urls>` to match all protocols.

Comment: Thanks for this reply Marco. I'm embarrassed to say that adding <all_urls> indeed solves the issue and was clearly an oversight on my part. I was originally trying to limit the number of permissions allotted to the extension, and I do have activeTab declared. Any insights on why triggering the same behavior with the hot key works? Or why that changes the behavior of the onUpdated code?

Comment: I don't know why you're experiencing that inconsistency with the keyboard shortcut. Looks like a bug, but I'm not sure. I haven't personally looked into that.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer me, it's much appreciated.

Comment: You're welcome. If I solved your problem you can accept my answer by clicking the green checkmark near it so that your question can be marked as solved.

Comment: Done! Thanks again!